# Increase CharField Width in Django Forms

Tags: django-forms

I am extending `UserCreationForm` and have added

```
username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'80'}))
```

but the username field width does not change. How can I increase it?

Answer (score 24):

Try specifying widgets in the form, as in the following example:

**models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

**admin.py**

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (u'preview', u'caption')
    search_fields = (u'caption')
    form = forms.PhotoAdminForm
```

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = { 'caption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 80})}
```

As alternative, you can use the following:

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    caption = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':80}))
```

Comment: So, regarding the code in the question: basically just remove the quotation marks on `'80'`?

Answer (score 4):

Since 1.7 you can solve it like this:

**admin.py**

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (u'preview', u'caption')
    search_fields = (u'caption')
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size': '80'})}
    }
```