# How to increase Django forms.Form CharField Size

Tags: django, forms, email

I've create following form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'special', 'size': '40'}))
```

But when I add data in Message field with some data it isn't coming up in my email associated with this form with settings mentioned in Settings.py. But full_name and email is coming up fine.

My view is:

```
def contact(request):
    title = "Contact Us"
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        form_message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
        form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
        subject = "Site Contact Form"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = [from_email, myemail@gmail.com']
        contact_message = "%s: %s via %s"%(form_full_name, form_message, form_email)
        html_template = "<h1>Hello There</h1>"
        send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, html_message=html_template, fail_silently=True)
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "title": title
    }
    return render(request, 'contact/form.html', context)
```

Also I need to know what would be the best option to create some form to recieve information directly to my email. Should I use models based form or simple form without models? Please advise as my message field text is not coming up in email but Name and email is coming up fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323886/charfield-increase-width

Comment: You realize that you have a syntax error in your view code right? There is a missing `'` in the `to_email` assignment.

Comment: To Usman Maqbool have you noticed that I am trying to increase size in forms.Form not in ModelForm. In ModelsForm I simply can use TextField and the text box will be broaden.

Comment: have you check value in 'contact_message' before sending email? is message is there or not?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special', 'size': '40'}))
```

Comment: Dharmik I exactly used this as an alternate but then the box size gets to same size of CharField.

Comment: M Hassan yes values are there.